# how to disable UAS for usb without knowing prior device id in grub?

Tags: usb, grub, uasp

I have a usb hub with external USB HDD disks.
I found out that seagate HDDs do not give smart information if UAS is enabled specifically in linux (due to copyrights?). [Here](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/971), read the discussion.

There is some options to disable UAS specifically for an usb device, if you know the device id. However, I have 3 problems with that:

- USB disks may are on or off when booting
- I suppose device id may change
- All 3 seagate disks in usb hub are given same device id.

```
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 0bc2:aa15 Seagate RSS LLC Basic
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0bc2:aa15 Seagate RSS LLC Basic
Bus 002 Device 023: ID 0bc2:aa15 Seagate RSS LLC Basic
```

The options to disable UAS are

- after booting: `sudo rmmod usb-storage` and `sudo modprobe usb-storage quirks=0bc2:aa15:u`. However, this does not work.`rmmod: ERROR: Module usb_storage is in use by: uas`.
- create new file `/etc/modprobe.d/disable-uas.conf` and add `options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:aa15:u` then `update-initramfs -u`
- edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX: ="usb-storage.quirks=0bc2:aa15:u"`
- (newly found) `echo "0bc2:aa15:u"" | sudo tee /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks` but dont work also.

First option dont work. Other options require to know the device ID beforehand, even usb disks are turnt off and open after booting, even if i have turnt them on, after booting they may get any id (see problems).

What I can do?

Comment: Device ID and Vendor ID are not properties of a specific device but of a model. They do not change except maybe on mode-switching USB devices (like cellular modems).

Comment: USB vendor and device ids are not given by the OS, but an embedded information in the device itself, so it does not change unless you have replaced it with another drive (of different model). I don't think whether the drive is on/connected matters, because it just make the driver loaded into the memory work differently when a matched device gets plugged in. (I'm not entirely sure though. TIAS.) There's probably nothing you can do regarding the third problem: it's either none or all. If you don't like it, use drives of different models (or modify the firmware so that they have different ids.)

Comment: @tomyan dont knew that! Thanks I try and report back! If successful, i will tell you to post it as an answer.

Comment: @tomYan worked! thanks! you may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

USB vendor and device ids are not given by the OS, but an embedded information in the device itself, so it does not change unless you have replaced it with another drive (of different model).

Whether the drive is on/connected does not matter, because the module param just make the driver loaded into the memory work differently when a matched device gets plugged in.

There's probably nothing you can do regarding the third problem: it's either none or all. If you don't like it, use drives of different models (or modify the firmware so that they have different ids.)